# Why do sun light rays that come through clouds not look parallel, despite it being so far?

Tags: astronomy, atmospheric-science, sun

I was at the airport last friday and there were some nice sun light rays, although not much of a good spot to take a picture. What weirds me out every time I see them is that they look as if coming from a ball of light pretty much right behind the clouds. I drew some lines to illustrate that:

[image]

I never stopped to think about this before. Why are they not parallel, is it some kind of illusion?

In case astronomy matters to explain this, the picture was taken at 7pm, February in central Europe.

Comment: @JohnRennie Yeah, didn't find that one. Thanks.